# Can the intersection two non-recursive sets be recursive? Prove it

Tags: turing-machines, computability

I am still really new to compsci theory and some of the topics are really hard to understand. For this Problem I would think that say we have two sets A and B and they are both non-recursive.
If we take  A ∩ B we would get the the matching inputs and since they are both from non-recursive sets wouldn't the  intersection also be non-recursive? or am I thinking about this the wrong way. Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: One easy way to produce disjoint non-recursive language can be to take your favorite non-recursive language $L$ and consider the language $L_0$ that consists of the words of $L$, but inserting a $0$ in front of each letter. Then define $L_1$ in the same way, but inserting a $1$ in front of every letter. The languages $L_0$ and $L_1$ are still non-recursive and are disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be a non-recursive set. Let $L_0 = \{0 \cdot x \mid x \in L\}$ and $L_1 = \{1 \cdot x \mid x \in L\}$. Both $L_0$ and $L_1$ are non-recursive, but $L_0 \cap L_1 = \emptyset$ is recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: there are such languages.

Take some language $L\notin RE\cup co-RE$ (look at the explanation at the end for why such a language exists). Then both $L$ and $\bar L$ are not recursive, and are not even recursively enumerable. But, its obvious that $\emptyset=L\cap \bar L$ **is** a recursive set.

**Claim: there is some $L\notin RE\cup co-RE$.**

**Proof:**
Why would such $L$ exist? We will compare the sizes of $RE\cup co-RE$ and the set of all languages.

$RE$ contains only $\aleph_0$ languages, since each language has to be recognized by some turing machine, and turing machines we can ultimately be encoded in text. More formally, we know that for any $A\in RE$ we must have some turing machine $T$ that recognizes it, and $\langle T \rangle\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. But $|\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}|=\aleph_0$, and thus $|RE|\le\#\text{TM}\le|\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}|=\aleph_0$. A similar argument can be done to show that also $|co-RE|=\aleph_0$ and combining the two, we get $|RE\cup co-RE| = \aleph_0$

Now, notice that the set of all languages, is precisely $P(\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}})$, and thus it has $2^{\aleph_0}$ elements in it. Since $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$, there must be some $L\in P(\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}})$ such that $L\notin RE\cup co-RE$, and thus we proved the claim.